# Write/Load OpenEXR compress file

Tags: c++, c++11, run-length-encoding, openexr

I made an openEXR save and load functions. The load takes a stack of .hdr files from a directory and then the save function writes the .exr file which "merges" the .hdr files in one .exr file.

This is working well but the .hdr files were RLE compressed and I didn't find the way with the OpenEXR library to compress the .exr file.

Though, I know OpenEXR file can compress in RLE. Has anyone found how to do that in c++ ? The documentation is here : http://www.openexr.com/openexrfilelayout.pdf but it does not really explain how to perform that...

Comment: Do you mean this? https://github.com/openexr/openexr/blob/891437f74805f6c8ebc897932091cbe0bb7e1163/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfRle.cpp

Comment: What I wondered is, is there a way the openEXR format can detect wether the datas are compress or not ? I they are then it would uncompress them when reading the .exr filer. 
For instance, is there a header channel name convention to decide if the datas to load must be uncompress by rleUncompress() that you linked ?